# Store custom classes object in coredata

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to store `MCOIMAPMessage` class object in coredata. 
I want to store that object in coredata and fetch it.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can store any object in CoreData.
For more information, please check out [Managed Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html).
( especially `Custom Managed Object Classes` section )